# What is a good way to implement tags on a posts like SO

Tags: database-design, tags

I want a tag system like whats on SO but Im not sure how to implement this in the database. This is how i was going to implement it.

Here are my columns in the database

**Article Table**

- ID
- Title
- TitleSlug
- Date
- UserID
- Description
- IsDeleted
- TagID1
- TagID2
- TagID3
- TagID4
- TagID5
- TagName1
- TagName2
- TagName3
- TagName4
- TagName5

**Tag table**

- TagID
- TagName

Is this a good way to implement tags in the database?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480949/

Comment: first related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a many-to-many relationship table structure so something like:

Article Table

- ID
- Title
- TitleSlug
- Date
- UserID
- Description
- IsDeleted

Tag table

- TagID
- TagName

Relationship Table

- articleId
- tagId

This way you can have unlimited relationships, where your example is limited to 5