# How to design querying multiple tags on analytics database

Tags: performance, amazon-redshift, database-tuning

I would like to store user purchase custom tags on each transaction, example if user bought  shoes then tags are `"SPORTS", "NIKE", SHOES, COLOUR_BLACK, SIZE_12,..`

These tags are that seller interested in querying back to understand the sales.

My idea is when ever new tag comes in create new code(something like hashcode but sequential) for that tag, and code starts from `"a-z"` 26 letters then `"aa, ab, ac...zz"` goes on. Now keep all the tags given for in one transaction in the one column called `tag (varchar)` by separating with `"|"`.

Let us assume mapping is (at application level)

```
"SPORTS" = a
"TENNIS" = b
"CRICKET" = c
...
...
"NIKE"  = z        //Brands company
"ADIDAS" = aa
"WOODLAND" = ab
...
...
SHOES   = ay
...
...
COLOUR_BLACK = bc
COLOUR_RED = bd
COLOUR_BLUE = be
...
SIZE_12 = cq
...
```

So storing the above purchase transaction, tag will be like `tag="|a|z|ay|bc|cq|"` And now allowing seller to search number of SHOES sold by adding `WHERE` condition `tag LIKE %|ay|%`. Now the problem is i cannot use index (sort key in redshift db) for "LIKE starts with %". So how to solve this issue, since i might have 100 millions of records? dont want full table scan..

any solution to fix this?

Update_1:
I have not followed `bridge table` concept (cross-reference table) since I want to perform group by on the results after searching the specified tags. My solution will give only one row when two tags matched in a single transaction, but bridge table will give me two rows? then my sum() will be doubled.

I got suggestion like below

> EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transaction_tag WHERE tag_id = 'zz' and trans_id
>   = tr.trans_id) in the WHERE clause once for each tag (note: assumes tr is an alias to the transaction table in the surrounding query)

I have not followed this; since i have to perform AND and OR condition on the tags, example ("SPORTS" AND "ADIDAS") ----  "SHOE" AND ("NIKE"  OR  "ADIDAS")

Update_2:
I have not followed bitfield, since dont know redshift has this support also  I assuming if my system will be going to have minimum of 3500 tags, and allocating one bit for each; which results in 437 bytes for each transaction, though there will be only max of 5 tags can be given for a transaction. Any optimisation here?

Solution_1:

I have thought of adding min (SMALL_INT) and max value (SMALL_INT) along with tags column, and apply index on that.

so something like this

```
"SPORTS" = a = 1
"TENNIS" = b = 2
"CRICKET" = c = 3
...
...
"NIKE"  = z  = 26
"ADIDAS" = aa = 27
```

So my column values are

```
`tag="|a|z|ay|bc|cq|"` //sorted?
`minTag=1`
`maxTag=95` //for cq
```

And query for searching shoe(ay=51) is

`maxTag <= 51 AND tag LIKE %|ay|%`

And query for searching shoe(ay=51) AND SIZE_12 (cq=95)  is

`minTag >= 51 AND maxTag <= 95 AND tag LIKE %|ay|%|cq|%`

Will this give any benefit? Kindly suggest any alternatives.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885564/ways-to-implement-tags-pros-and-cons-of-each

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810356/how-to-implement-tag-system

Answer (score 1):

You can implement auto-tagging while the files get loaded to S3. Tagging at the DB level is too-late in the process. Tedious and involves lot of hard-coding

1. While loading to S3 tag it using the AWS s3API
   example below
   aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket  --key   --tagging "TagSet=[{Key=Addidas,Value=AY}]"

capture tags dynamically by sending  and  as a parameter

2.load the tags to dynamodb as a metadata store

3.load data to Redshift using S3 COPY command

Comment: Thanks! but I need to study about this, and get back to you. What i understand on S3 copy command is; it used to batch insert rows from file. For me each row will have different tags, but copy command is once for all the batch insert....

Answer (score 1):

You can store tags column as varchar bit mask, i.e. a strictly defined bit sequence of 1s or 0s, so that if a purchase is marked by a tag there will be 1 and if not there will be 0, etc. For every row, you will have a sequence of 0s and 1s that has the same length as the number of tags you have. This sequence is sortable, however you would still need lookup into the middle but you will know at which specific position to look so you don't need `like`, just `substring`. For further optimization, you can convert this bit mask to integer values (it will be unique for each sequence) and make matching based on that but AFAIK Redshift doesn't support that yet out of box, you will have to define the rules yourself.

UPD: Looks like the best option here is to keep tags in a separate table and create an ETL process that unwraps tags into tabular structure of `order_id, tag_id`, distributed by `order_id` and sorted by `tag_id`. Optionally, you can create a view that joins the this one with the order table. Then lookups for orders with a particular tag and further aggregations of orders should be efficient. There is no silver bullet for optimizing this in a flat table, at least I don't know of such that would not bring a lot of unnecessary complexity versus "relational" solution.

Comment: Thank you! @AlexYes. I thought of that, but I assuming my system will be going to have minimum of 3500 tags which results in 437 bytes for each transaction, though there will be maximum of 5 tags can be given for a transaction. Any optimisation here?

Comment: One way is to encode everything to integer but I can't advise here much since I haven't tried it, another way I would think of is more "relational" - you create a table that has `order_id, tag_id`, distributed by `order_id` and sorted by `tag_id` and create a view that joins the this one with the order table. Then lookups for particular tag and further aggregations of orders should be efficient. I don't think there is any other way to optimize that in a flat row.

Comment: Apart from the above, your tags don't seem to be custom. From what you specified, it is just "designation", "brand", "color" and "size" and it is much better to store them as raw values in separate encoded columns.